# How to access ComboBox selected item in code behind

Tags: combobox, selecteditem, avaloniaui

I would like to access the SelectedItem property for a ComboBox.

In WPF, the properties can be called by Name.Property (i.e. ComboBoxName.SelectedItem). I want to know what item is currently selected in the ComboBox, which is why I need to do this, but it is telling me the name doesn't exist in the current context. I have a SelectionChanged event handler that I want to update a string with the current selected item when it is changed.

.xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="Generation" Items="{Binding Generation}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="Gen_SelectionChanged"/>
```

.xaml.cs

```
private void Gen_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
   var SelectedItem = Generation.SelectedItem;
}
```

The error I recieve when doing this is for the Generation in Generation.SelectedItem, telling me "The name "Generation" does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated C# fields aren't supported yet. You can use `this.FindControl<ComboBox>("Generation")` after loading XAML instead.